# Установка React, ошибка с версиями

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Установил nodejs. с версиями какая-то путаница (скрин ниже). При попытке установить react, показывает ошибку, мол обновите нод, чтобы версия была 14+. А она вроде как 15.0.0... Или 10.19.0. В общем продолжить работу не могу, что предпринять для устранения данной ошибки?[image: Проверка версий node]
[image: Ошибка при установке react]

Answer (score 0):

Мне для решения аналогичной проблемы помогли следующие 5 шагов :
1)curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o nodesource_setup.sh

2)Проверьте содержимое загруженного скрипта с помощью nano (или предпочитаемого вами текстового редактора): nano nodesource_setup.sh

3)Когда вы убедитесь, что скрипт можно запускать безопасно, выйдите из редактора, а затем запустите скрипт с помощью sudo:sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh

4)sudo apt install nodejs

5)node -v

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).